# Angular 9/10 not able to subscribe to both Params and Query Params. This was working in Angular 8 and less version

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

```
 this.router.navigate(['/lp/flights/0'],{queryParams:{requestId : this.requestId}});
```

In app-routing.module.ts

```
{
    path: 'lp/flights/:destcode',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import(
        './ytb-modules/flight/flight-landing/flight-landing.module'
      ).then((m) => m.FlightLandingModule),
  },
```

Here , it is subscribing only to route params , and in the browser address bar only h**ttp://localhost:4200/lp/flights/0 is shown rather than http://localhost:4200/lp/flights/0?requestId=xxxx**

queryParams is removed while router.navigate(), this behaviour was not there in Angular 8.

Comment: I tried reproducing it, but I can't. Can you setup a Stackblitz or a Repo where the error is reproduced?

Comment: Can you try with `queryParamsHandling: "merge"` ? https://angular.io/api/router/UrlCreationOptions#queryParamsHandling